# Illegal mix of collations -- Simple PHP Login

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to make a simple php login and running into some issues, here's the error:

> Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='

Here's the query

```
SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `username` = :user AND `password` = MD5(CONCAT(MD5(`salt`), MD5(:pass)))
```

Where `:user` and `:pass` are preparred statement parameters containing th e username and password.

I'm trying to simulate `md5(md5(salt).md5(pass))` in the query.

Using PDO php.

Comment: You really shouldn't use your own salts on password hashes and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the MySql manual on [MD5](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html), the collation result of the MD5 function is the same as your system or connection settings.

I would guess that your column collations are set different from your system settings.

You could specify your collation settings when creating your connection.
See [opening PDO connection](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php).

Without testing, I think something like this would work:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=latin1_swedish_ci';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$options = array(
   ...
); 

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
```

Comment: Could you provide information on where to do this with PDO? This even occurs when trying to execute the query through `PhpMyAdmin` as-well.

Comment: I don't know how to specify the character set when opening an existing database in PhpMyAdmin.  However, you can change the system setting for the database in the Operations tab.